# linq querying entity framework how to join tables? navigation properties?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Hi there I am stuck on a problem and hope someone can explain the answer to me!

So in my database I have 3 tables that connect like this:

```
Customer         CustomerAddress        Address
-CustomerID      -CustomerID            -AddressID
-FirstName       -AddressID             -Street
-LastName                               -City
```

So I create my entity model and the middle table(CustomerAddress) is removed and replaced by navigation properties?

So what I'm trying to do is join the tables using a LINQ query in C#.
in SQl the query would look something like this:

```
Select *
From dbo.customer as c
left join dbo.customeraddress as ca on c.customerID = ca.customerID
left Join dbo.Address as a on a.addressID = ca.addressID
```

I realise thats not the case here since there is no customeraddress table. Do I use the navigation properties columns to make a join? In my model diagram I notice there is a navigation property called Addresses in the Customer class/table that seems to map to the Address class/table property called Customers.

So I've tried this:

```
var customerQuery = (from customer in db.Customers
                     join address in db.Addresses on customer.Addresses equals address.Customers into add
                     from rt2 in add.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new { //.. });
```

But that is obviously incorrect, as I am unsure what to do with the navigation properties to join them. I would really appreciate if anyone could explain to me how I go about joining with this model!

Comment: Why not make em one table anyway? Though just to be clear you want to join em so you could select from the joined tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have navigation properties, you just use them in your queries like what you would do if they were objects - there is no need to use joins, EF will generate them for you.

For instance, your query would be like this:

```
var customerQuery = (from customer in db.Customers
                     from address in customer.Addresses.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new { //.. });
```

This will generate `left outer join` for you. If you want `inner join`, remove `DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Comment: Thank you very much this is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: What if the relationship between customer and address is 1:1?  The DefaultIfEmpty method is not available then.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  It would look like `db.Customers.Where(c=>c.Address).DefaultIfEmpty();`